# what is keyAlias="aaaa" in tomcat server.xml file

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https, keystore

I have SSL certificate purchased and installed into tomcat. I created `tomcat.keystore` file which I include in `server.xml` file also put password but not able to understand `keyAlias="aaa"`. If I put keyAlias="localhost" then I get exception given below. And if I remove `keyAlias` itself from the Connector tag then I get another exception which is given below next `localhost` exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Alias name localhost does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:649)
```

Here is exception after removing `keyAlias` itself from the `Connector` tag.

```
Aug 08, 2015 2:39:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:443
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:649)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(SSLServerSocket.java:136)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:107)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:219)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    ... 17 more
```

Following is the content of `server.xml` file.

```
<Connector port="443" SSLEnabled="true" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="tomcat.keystore"
           keystorePass="test" keyAlias="aaa"/>
```

What is that `keyAlias` ? Why am I getting exception after removing it which is Binding exception ?

Comment: I don't think the `Address already in use` issue is connected to the removal of keyAlias.

Comment: @keyser yet it is an issue by removing that `keyAlias`. It gives Binding exception into Catalina.out file. My application is running on 443 with  http(not https). But the question what is the value for `keyAlias="?"` so that I can actually host my application on https.

Comment: But with the address issue you should simply be able to free up the port. Did you check what's using it, if anything? If it's related it's weird.

Answer (score 6):

KEYALIAS:

https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-tomcat.htm`

1. When you import your certificate into the keystore, you would typically give an "alias":

   `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias server -file your_site_name.p7b -keystore your_site_name.jks`
2. In your server.xml, you must then declare the *same* "alias":

   `<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" 
     minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false"
     disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https" 
     secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
     keyAlias="server" keystoreFile="/home/user_name/your_site_name.jks"
     keystorePass="your_keystore_password" />`
3. Here are some other links that might help:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl

https://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/tomcat-ssl/

SECOND ISSUE, "CAN'T BIND":

As far as "address in use", I would simply try rebooting the server and see if Tomcat starts correctly.

If you encounter the error again,

1. Look in your Tomcat settings to see which port you're trying to use (e.g. 443)
2. Check your system to see who else is using the port (lsof, nmap, etc):

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28609/how-can-i-tell-what-is-listening-on-a-tcpip-port-in-windows/

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Security_Guide/s1-server-ports.html

Comment: I am very much near to answer from your answer. Can you please help me which one is keyAlias. I had executed three command while creating tomcat.keystore file.......1. keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gdig2.crt
2.keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
3. keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file 9999999999.crt

Answer (score -1):

These errors are not related.

1. `keyAlias` is documented in the Tomcat documentation, and that is where you should look for its meaning.
2. The error you have made is to not import the signed certificate with the same alias you used when generating the keypair. They must be the same so that they keytool will associate the keypair with the certificate and create a key entry instead of a certificate entry.
3. The `BindException` means that some other process, probably a prior invocation of Tomcat that hasn't exited yet, is using the port. Or possibly you have configured two Connectors to use the same port. It only shows up as an error when you configure the SSL connector correctly.