# Tomcat 9 starts with the error log entry “Alias name [mykey] does not identify a key entry”

Tags: tomcat, https

How to enable scheme="https" on a Tomcat 9 using a Java keystore of type JKS?

Starting Tomcat 9 shows the error log entry **“Alias name [mykey] does not identify a key entry”**.
My Java Keystore is of type JKS. It has just one entry named “mykey” and this is a “trustedCertEntry”.

The Tomcat server.xml contains following configuration:

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" 
           maxThreads="150" 
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks" 
           keystorePass="changeit"
           keyAlias="mykey"
           clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           >
</Connector>
```

I’m sure, that I access the right keystoreFile. When changing to a different path or password it shows the expected error. When removing the keyAlias= then I get the same error message, where mykey is replaced with null.

Any hints on this? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is keyAlias=“aaaa” in tomcat server.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31897461/2985643).

Comment: I have read the page and links carefully, but the error still exists