# How to configure a certificate to be used for https

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 5.0.0
I have a keystore that is currently signing the tokens generated by IS and is also used for https, when we access the console at https://servername:9443

```
<Security>
        <!--
            KeyStore which will be used for encrypting/decrypting passwords
            and other sensitive information.
        -->
        <KeyStore>
            <!-- Keystore file location-->
            <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/samlwso2-internal.***.com.jks</Location>
            <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->
            <Type>JKS</Type>
            <!-- Keystore password-->
            <Password>*******!</Password>
            <!-- Private Key alias-->
            <KeyAlias>samlwso2-internal.***.com</KeyAlias>
            <!-- Private Key password-->
            <KeyPassword>******!</KeyPassword>
        </KeyStore>
...
</Security>
```

I have another c2wso2.***.com.jks that has the certificate that I would like to use for https. Any pointers on configuring this?

I tried updating the security->keystore node with the c2wso2.***.com.jks, at which point, it was using this cert for both https and signing the tokens. This is expected, but I am not seeing a way to use a different cert for each of these functions

Also tried updating /repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml file as mentioned in https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB211/Changing+Default+Keystores. I thought this would force it to use this cert for https, but did  not have any impact.

Comment: Can you double check the configuration on catalina-server.xml with this documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+Keystores+in+WSO2+Products#ConfiguringKeystoresinWSO2Products-ConfiguringakeystoreforSSLconnectionsConfiguringasecondarykeystore(forSSLconnections)

Comment: <Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                port="9443"
                bindOnInit="false"
                sslProtocol="TLS"
                . . .                                                                                           
                compression="on"
                scheme="https"
                secure="true"
                SSLEnabled="true"
                . . . keystoreFile="${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/c2wso2.****.com.jks"
    keystorePass="****!"
                URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

Comment: @BuddhimaUdaranga, confirmed above that I have the keystore details in the connector config in catalina-server.xml. Restarted wso2, but still seems to be using the certfiicate in the keystore specified in carbon.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are having multiple private key entries in the keystore, try specifying the key alias in the connector config as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31897552/2910841